# Is there a better looking way to compare 3 values that may or may not be 0 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare 3 different values that may be 0 or greater. Is the only way to do it with multiple else-if statements? This is what I have right now but I just feel like there must be a better way:

```js
//just A
if (A > 0 && B == 0 && C == 0){//Do something}
//just B
else if (A == 0 && B > 0 && C == 0){//Do something}
//just C
else if (A == 0 && B == 0 && C > 0){//Do something}

//A + B
else if (A > 0 && B > 0 && C == 0){//Do something}
//A + C
else if (A > 0 && B == 0 && C > 0){//Do something}
//B + C
else if (A == 0 && B > 0 && C > 0){//Do something}

//A + B + C
else if (A > 0 && B > 0 && C > 0){//Do something}

else {//Do something}
```

Comment: depending on what happens there is probably different ways of handling this

Comment: That depends: Do you need to distinguish between all combinations of "A is greater than zero, but B and C are not" or do you just want to know, if either one of them is greater? More context is needed to answer your question.

Comment: `//Do something` is equivalent to: `A + B`, `A + C`, ..., `A + B + C` ?

Comment: @Taxel Yes, I need to know all of the combinations..

Comment: I think there are no ways: that is the total of combination = 3 + 3 + 1 + 1  = 8 (possible cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think of each individual check as producing a value of 1 or 0 (true or false). If test values are A=2, B=0, C=99, then the check `A > 0` -> true -> 1 and `B == 0` -> false -> 0.

So if we combine each variation of the three checks for A, B and C, the results for the test values are as follows:

- none: `A == 0 && B == 0 && C == 0` -> false, false, false -> 000
- just A: `A > 0 && B == 0 && C == 0` -> true, false, false -> 100
- just C: `A == 0 && B == 0 && C > 0` -> false, false, true -> 001
- just B: `A == 0 && B > 0 && C == 0` -> false, true, false -> 010
- B + C: `A == 0 && B > 0 && C > 0` -> false, true, true -> 011
- A + C: `A > 0 && B == 0 && C > 0` -> true, false, true -> 101
- A + B: `A > 0 && B > 0 && C == 0` -> true, true, false -> 110
- A + B + C: `A > 0 && B > 0 && C > 0` -> true, true, true -> 111

You could use [binary numbers](http://qnimate.com/javascript-0b-literal/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9C0b%E2%80%9D%20lets%20you%20create%20a,binary%20of%20the%20number%20directly.) as keys to an object from which to get the action you would like to execute. This is the `variants` object in the example. You can replace the console.logs with actual 'do something' logic you need.

What `const key = (+!!A << 2) + (+!!B << 1) + !!C;` does:

1. Convert each number to a boolean - `!!A` -> true, `!!B` -> false (for the test values (A=2, B=0, C=99)
2. Convert the boolean to a number - `+true` -> 1, `+false` -> 0
3. Shift it to the appropriate bit position - `1<<2` -> 100 (binary) -> 4 (decimal), `0<<1` is still 0,
4. Sum the numbers - 4 + 0 + 1 -> 5 -> 0b101

```js
const variants = {
  [0b000]() {console.log('none/default')},
  [0b001]() {console.log('just C')},
  [0b010]() {console.log('just B')},
  [0b011]() {console.log('B+C')},
  [0b100]() {console.log('just A')},
  [0b101]() {console.log('A+C')},
  [0b110]() {console.log('A+B')},
  [0b111]() {console.log('A+B+C')},
}

const A = 2;
const B = 0;
const C = 99;

const key = (+!!A << 2) + (+!!B << 1) + !!C;

variants[key]();
```

**Option 2**

If using binary numbers and bitwise operations are confusing, you could use string representation of a binary number.

```js
const variants = {
    '000': () => {console.log('none/default')},
    '010': () => {console.log('just B')},
   // the rest of the keys
}
const bitA = A ? 1 : 0;
const bitB = B ? 1 : 0;
const bitC = C ? 1 : 0;

const key = `${bitA}${bitB}${bitC}`;
variants[key]();
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me...

Comment: I added a clarification how we go from boolean checks to zeros and ones. Is clearer now?

Comment: Whops, I didn't actually mean to edit it, but only to *suggest* an edit. Feel free to revert it!

Comment: Thanks for the edits @ZER0! I updated the explanation with more details what the dark magic `(+!!A << 2) + (+!!B << 1) + !!C;` does and pasted as option 2 the solution with strings for people like me, who are not that advanced with type coercion and bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 variables (a, b, c) with 2 possible (> 0 or <= 0) states which means you have 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 cases in total. One way is to represent them as bits

```js
const toBits = (a, b, c) = {
  const toBit = val => val > 0 ? '1' : '0'
  return toBit(a) + toBit(b) + toBit(c)
}

const cases = {
  '000': () => { // do something },
  '001': () => { // do something },
  '010': () => { // do something },
  '011': () => { // do something },
  '100': () => { // do something },
  '101': () => { // do something },
  '110': () => { // do something },
  '111': () => { // do something },
}

const bitsRepresentation = toBits(a, b, c)
const runCase = cases[bitsRepresentation]

runCase()
```

Another option is to use switch in kinda inverted way

```
const aFlag = a > 0
const bFlag = b > 0
const cFlag = c > 0

switch (true) {
  case (!aFlag && !bFlag && !cFlag):
    // do something  
  case (!aFlag && !bFlag && cFlag):
    // do something  
  case (!aFlag && bFlag && !cFlag):
    // do something  
  case (!aFlag && bFlag && cFlag):
    // do something  
  case (aFlag && !bFlag && !cFlag):
    // do something  
  case (aFlag && !bFlag && cFlag):
    // do something  
  case (aFlag && bFlag && !cFlag):
    // do something  
  case (aFlag && bFlag && cFlag):
    // do something  
  default:
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the first option you showed..

Comment: You do not understand how options are represented with bits or how to map values to  functions?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you really need to strictly distinguish between all 8 of those scenarios, but if you still need all 8 of those, I guess you could check each of a, b, and c once, and assign them to booleans instead of repeatedly checking them:

```
aFlag = (A > 0);
bFlag = (B > 0);
cFlag = (C > 0);

//just A
if (aFlag && !bFlag && !cFlag){//Do something}
//just B
else if (!aFlag && bFlag && !cFlag){//Do something}
//just C
else if (!aFlag && !bFlag && cFlag){//Do something}

//A + B
else if (aFlag && bFlag && !cFlag){//Do something}
//A + C
else if (aFlag && !bFlag && cFlag){//Do something}
//B + C
else if (!aFlag && bFlag && cFlag){//Do something}

//A + B + C
else if (aFlag && bFlag && cFlag){//Do something}

else {//Do something}
```

This probably isn't much faster, but, at least in my opinion, it seems a bit easier to look at.

I guess you could also change it to some form of nested if statements, rather than a linear series of else-if statements:

```
if (A > 0) {
    if (B > 0) {
        if (C > 0) {
            //A + B + C
        } else {
            //A + B
        }
    } else {
        if (C > 0) {
            //A + C
        } else {
            //just A
        }
    }
} else {
    if (B > 0) {
        if (C > 0) {
            //B + C
        } else {
            //just B
        }
    } else {
        if (C > 0) {
            //just C
        } else {
            //None
        }
    }
}
```

This looks really messy, but it would only do 3 checks total, instead of a possible 7 for your implementation.

Comment: Yes, I do need to distinguish between them all..  I considered the second option you showed but it does seem messier than what I had..

Comment: Well, if you can't share code between any of them (for example, if "A + B" was the code for "just A" plus the code for "just B"), it seems like you're going to have to do something long-winded like this. I don't think there's a better option.  Maybe you could do a switch-case statement, but you'd have to fiddle with the input a bit, and I don't think it would be much better in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reduce the else if statements but you can reduce the conditions inside each if condition. I would suggest to make a sum of all 3 variables and check whether particular value is matching with sum or not.

Here is my suggestion:

```
const sum = A + B + C;
//just A
if (A == sum){//Do something
}
//just B
else if (B == sum){//Do something
}
//just C
else if (C == sum){//Do something
}

//A + B
else if (A + B == sum){//Do something
}
//A + C
else if (A + C  == sum){//Do something
}
//B + C
else if (B + C  == sum){//Do something
}

//A + B + C
else if (A + B + C == sum){//Do something
}

else {//Do something
}
```

As per the question I am assuming you have `A, B and C` are numbers and greater or equal to 0.

Comment: This makes sense but seems to be pretty similar to what I'm currently doing. Not sure if it's much of an improvement but thanks.

Comment: True but now you have less conditions which makes solution faster.